# jQuery Scrolling Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

everyone!
I am trying to show a div when user scrolls past another div and hide it again when user reaches the beginning of the latter div.
Let's say, we have two divs with IDs #1 and #2. Now, when the user scrolls to the beginning of #1, div#2 is shown. When, again, user comes back to #1, div#2 is hidden. How can I achieve this?

I was using this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if(y>0){
            jQuery("#2").slideDown();
        } 
        if(y==0){
            jQuery("#2").slideUp();
        }
    });
```

which worked perfectly for scrolling on window. But this didn't work:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        y = jQuery("#1").scrollTop();
        if(y>0){
            jQuery("#2").slideDown();
        } 
        if(y==0){
            jQuery("#2").slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Am I doing it wrong? Help much appreciated.

Comment: You have a syntax error, y = jQuery("#1).scrollTop(); should be y = jQuery("#1").scrollTop();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what scrollTop is to div #1. You say, if `y > 0`. Unless div1 itself is scrollable, it will always be zero. What you really want is whether the *window* is below div1. So for that we use

```
//top of window is at
jQuery(window).scrollTop();

//top of div1 is at (relative to window)
jQuery('#1').offset().top;

//your code should look like this instead
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(y>jQuery('#1'.offset().top)){
        jQuery("#2").slideDown();
    } 
    else{
        jQuery("#2").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: i edited my answer. forgot to correct the second half of your if statement.